# Channel artifacts in Unet model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Iam working with a Unet model, where the input are CT images and the output is a kind of heatmap. I noticed that I have artifacts in the images which I cannot get rid of. It is like the channels from the are visible in the output.

[image]

Does anyone else have experienced that?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

M

Comment: Channels from the ??? are....

Comment: Sounds like you're plotting without choosing a color map.

Comment: Hi Daniel and thanks for commenting.
The input channels consist of a stack of CT images. Iam using the jet colormap for plotting.